# How can I programically emulate the DllMain call in 64 bit windows?

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit

I'm not used to this whole 64 bit thing just yet, as I'm familiar with everything being on the stack.  For example, if I wanted to emulate DllMain in assembly on windows 32, i'd just do this:

```
__declspec(naked) void DllCall_Stub(HMODULE hModule)
{
    _asm
    {
        push 0;
        push 1;
        push [esp + 0Ch]
        mov eax, 0x12345678;        
        call eax;
        ret;
    }
} __declspec(naked) void DllCallStubEnd(void){}
```

However, on windows 64 it apparently passes the arguments through registers.

What is the equivalent to do this on a 64 bit process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate assembly code from C code in x64 when building with MSVC. Because it does not allow inline assembly anymore. In Windows x64, `RCX` is the first argument, `RDX` is second, `R8` and `R9` is the third and fourth, the remaining is passed via stack. And you need to allocate stack for all parameter you have passed, even for the first four parameters that passed on register. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286(v=vs.110).aspx for more informations.